# Discord.py Rewrite Cogs: Load extensions from other archive

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When I try to load the config extension, which is located in the modules folder, I do it like this, but it doesnt work:

```
bot.load_extension("modules/config")
```

When I move this into the same folder in which the main python file exists, it works:

```
bot.load_extension("config")
```

So how can I load it from the modules folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`load_extension`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) docs:

> name (str) – The extension name to load. It must be dot separated like regular Python imports if accessing a sub-module. e.g. `foo.test` if you want to import `foo/test.py`.

So you're looking for `bot.load_extension("modules.config")`.